# Deep linking URLSchema not taking me to the app as desired when clicking on web link

Tags: swift, ios9, deep-linking

I am trying to design a app that deep links to a url as `http://www.bunty.com/page1`
To achieve that I tried to use the following details to my plist . You can view it in the screenshot. But this seems not to work as expected because when I try to open the link in Safari, it opens some other website but not my app. So what mistake am I doing and how to rectify it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't just override http:// protocol. iOS will always open a browser for http.

You have to use some custom scheme/protocol, like `myApp://page1`
Remember to enter a correct identifier, which is your app's bundle id.

[Here's a full tutorial](https://pulsate.readme.io/v2.0/docs/supporting-deep-links) I wrote on how to do that.

Comment: So what should I do in order to achieve what I want? eg - If a link such as https://www.amazon.com/... is there, iOS checks whether an app is there or not and if it finds one it would open the app else it would open the site in the browser.

Comment: The question is on how to make deeplinks work in an app, you're asking something entirely else in a comment - you should create a separate question for that. This might help you though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435029/ios-and-android-shared-http-deep-linking

Answer (score 0):

change the `http` to `myApp` and visit the url in Safari using `myApp://page1`

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set the the `Bundle display name` in you info.plist to your apps name. This is used to create the popup message that says "current app would like to launch Bunty" and if it is nil the app will crash. This is different then the `Bundle Name` here is a screen shot of my schedule app.[image: displayNameVsName]