# Is it possible to deep link into the native iOS and Android Docusign app?

Tags: docusignapi, deep-linking

I am building a hybrid mobile application that has a requirement for offline Docusign functionality. Unfortunately, the only Docusign SDK that supports offline document signing is the native iOS SDK. I dont have the ability to build the offline sync myself leveraging the nodejs SDK either.

Does anyone have experience deep linking into the iOS and Android Docusign mobile app? I am struggling to find any information on deep linking into the docusign app from a 3rd party app.

I would like to deep link into the native docusign app in order to use a multi app solution to support the offline signature capture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS and Android Shared HTTP Deep Linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435029/ios-and-android-shared-http-deep-linking)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I’m not asking how to deep link in general but instead if anyone has experience deep linking into a specific app (DocuSign) that does not have any documentation detailing its url schema.

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time, maybe a future feature, but there's no plan right now to support deeplinking for third party developers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android SDK is available now with offline signing support https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk

Comment: Not sure why my previous answer which was a valid answer to Ben's question was deleted by the moderator