# Deep Link to a Document in the Android Docusign App

Tags: android, docusignapi, deep-linking

I have an exiting app that lists delivery jobs and has links to Docusign docs that need signing using inperson signing.
I also need the offline functionality that the native apps give, but without replicating it all in my existing app. Why rewrite what already exists right?
I was hoping that there would be a way to jump from my app to the right doc in the docusign app without the drivers needing to search manually. e.g. deep-linking

I've looked at the existing question below that is over a year old and wondered if anyone has got a solution yet?

[Is it possible to deep link into the native IOS and Android Docusign app>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133243/is-it-possible-to-deep-link-into-the-native-ios-and-android-docusign-app/64684727#64684727)

Comment: What's do you want? Could you please describe more detail the flows that's you want to do?
I understand that You need to open a screen in the other app from your app, that's right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign currently does not support app deep linking into the Android app. We recommend you take a look at the [Mobile SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/ios_sdk/developer.html) for any integrations. With the SDK, you're able to sign existing envelopes while online, and create/sign envelopes offline.

Comment: Is this the situatin in 2023? No url scheme for iOS DocuSign app?

Comment: Slava, this is not possible, because of security concerns. User of the iOS DocuSign app must be logged-in and that user must be the one that gets the envelope. IF that's the case - they can get push notification and sign from there, not directly from your code. You could use the iOS SDK and build this feature into your own app though.